# Yet another Java classpath problem

Tags: java, javac, noclassdeffounderror

I've been working on a project in Netbeans. Now I'd like to submit it and allow the markers to compile it with a script. However, I get the NoClassDefFoundError when I try to run via the command line. Even when setting the classpath to the current directory manually.

javac Main.java works fine

then calling java -classpath . Main gives:

```
java -classpath . Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: pro
ject2/Main)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:12
4)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have a package named `project2`. If that is intentional, you should use `project2.Main` as the class name on the command line, and the classpath contain the parent of the `project2` directory. If it is not intentional, remove or replace the `package project2;` at the top of the source file.

Comment: Thanks. I realised a few minutes after posting this question. Graargh stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword here is the "wrong name" in the stack trace. You can google that and find out that  there is a problem with packages.